# Can we have a tag for scientific-computing?

Tags: discussion

A lot of people use Ubuntu for scientific computing.

Can we have a tag for it?

Many of the questions like [this](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=octave), [this](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=mathematica), [this](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=numpy) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=julia) will fall under this category.

Comment: Is there a reason those specific tags for specific flavors/etc of scientific computing stuff is insufficient?  "scientific-computing" sounds like a meta-tag that should be more narrow with the tags you specify

Comment: It is always good to have a discussion on Meta on such issues but the ability to create new tags, and then subsequently  *populate* this tag throughout Ask Ubuntu, is granted after 300 Rep points: https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/create-tags. But it will be interesting nevertheless to see what the Community thinks of this particular tag proposition...

Comment: What purpose would such a tag serve? How would it be useful for filtering out or filtering in questions? Who would follow such a tag and curate it?

Comment: @muru There are questions like this https://askubuntu.com/q/1034034/124466, which sometimes get comments like "how is that relevant in Ask Ubuntu?", and sometimes get close votes, which is very fraustrating for new users. If we have a tag for scientific-computing-in-ubuntu, it can stop (aggressive) close-voters.

Comment: Having a tag does not make it any more on topic, though. We see that argument on occasion for questions on [tag:debian], [tag:linux-mint], etc., which is very frustrating too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you were going to go this route, I would recommend using the same [`data-science`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-science) terminology that Stack Overflow uses.  They may not be identical terms, but I think the software that you reference tends to lean towards "data science".

And there *might* be a case for there being unique `data-science` questions here on AU, **but** the vast majority of those in your searches certainly don't seem to qualify, IMHO.  Just looking through the [octave](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/octave) questions, for instance, the vast (vast, vast) majority are simply installation issues of one sort or another.

Honestly, I haven't found a single question *yet* in any of those tags that I would consider data-science and/or scientific-computing.  Not that I've exhausted, but I've skimmed through at least 60 questions in those tags without coming across a great candidate.

Answer (score 6):

This tag seems unnecessarily vague.

It's not even a single class of software (eg [calculator](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/calculator)), it barely an intention and broadly speaking, it would probably only serve as an umbrella around several tags which are otherwise more specifically tagged because they're *about* that software, not the intention.

I'm probably not being imaginative enough but I don't see who this tag would help.